# When I receive a chat invite, please notify me on the parent site and/or through the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, notifications, chat

I haven't really been involved in chat very much, but I was checking it out just now and it turns out I was made co-owner of a chat room! If I hadn't looked, I never would have known.

I think it would help a lot to get people involved in chat if these kinds of events are shown to users through the parent site (where the user *is* involved) in some way. Showing the event through the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ would be even better because then the user would get the notification through any of the sites.

I'm not sure exactly how common these events are, so I'm hoping users with more chat experience than me will provide answers with proposals for rate-limiting, which events should be communicated, etc., or even thoughts on whether or not this is a good idea.

Comment: How often does this actually happen? I wouldn't generally expect somebody to be invited to a room if they're not actually active in chat (and they can't be invited if they haven't at least been to chat once)

Comment: There are chat invites?

Comment: @Kobi - yes; if you have used chat other users can suggest rooms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting; I won't make any promises, but that sounds achievable.

Comment: Well, this is now completed. ♪ Could use an update to note this is live, rather than just "achievable".

Comment: @Grace - well, it was marked completed in November...?